# Sequences on an IQ Test

Tags: pattern, number-sequence, sequence

I found this IQ test (http://free.ultimaiq.net/nse.htm) and can't seem to solve questions 18 and 19:

Q18: 120, 10, 3, ?, ?

Q19: 41, 23, 61, ?

Comment: Please don't delete [a downvoted question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/112824/two-iq-test-sequences) and just repost it again. Instead consider whether there are ways to improve your original question.

Comment: It seems there are two distinct questions here, Q18 and Q19. Please ask them separately.

Comment: @Evargalo I don't think we need twice as many IQ test number sequence questions. It can be fine to include two puzzles in one post.

Answer (score 1):

**Partial Answer**

Q18

> This looks like the sequence [here](https://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C+10%2C+120&language=english&go=Search) written backwards.
>  In other words, the given elements correspond to the number of labeled cyclic subgroups of the symmetric groups $S_6, S_5$ and $S_4$, respectively, and the corresponding terms for $S_3$ and $S_2$ are **1** and **1**.
>  Typing this into the site we find that this is indeed the correct answer.

Q19 (incorrect answer which I like)

> If we reverse the digits of each element of the sequence, we get 14, 32, 16 which are the doubles of 7, 16, and 8, respectively. Looking at the face of a dartboard, we see that these numbers are clockwise adjacent and the next segment is 11 which, working backwards, would make the next number in the sequence **22**

Unfortunately, this is incorrect and the correct answer actually is

> 8
>  The best reasoning I can come up with for this goes back to reversing digits and dividing by two again to give 7, 16 and 8.
>  If we take the cube of these numbers we get **3**43, **4**096, **5**12 so the next entry would be the smallest number whose cube begins with **6** and that is 4.
>  Doubling and reversing indicates that the original missing entry should be **8**.

I'm willing to concede that there may be better explanations.

Comment: Q19 - my first thought was to do with prime numbers as 23, 41 and 61 are all primes. So I tried to figure out if there was a logic jump pattern between the primes. Starting from 41, you can jump back 4 primes to 23, and jump forward 5 primes from 41 to 61 (or 9 primes from 23). But that's not a clear pattern

Comment: @Trent also the answer as given by the site (ultimaiq) is not a prime but I agree, this could also have been a reasonable path.

Answer (score 1):

Q19: 41, 23, 61,
my thought is to multiply 41 * 3 and getting  123 then I take 123 and moltiply 12 * 3 getting 36 and then multiply 3 * 6 getting 18. the 1 of the nunmber 18 is already include in 61 so remains the digit 8.
41,23,61,8